# Compatibility of Shimano Ultegra and Sora components

Tags: shimano, chain, cassette, chainring, compatibility

My road bike has an Ultegra groupset, but some parts need replacement (chainrings, chain, and cassette). The chain is worn out, the cassette is sliding with a new chain, and the chainset is also worn out. Can I keep my 3-9 derailleurs and mount new Ultegra chainrings with a Sora cassette (9) and a Sora chain to save some money, or should I keep riding and mount ultegra chainrings, chain, and cassette when they are fully worn out?

Answer (score -1):

- Most groupset parts don't wear out on a predictable replacement schedule. Derailleurs, brakes, cranks, and brifters should last for a long time, barring unusual wear or crashes. And I hate to say it, but if you do get to the point where you want to replace those parts, it might be cheaper to buy a new bike.
- Modern Sora and Ultegra chainrings are 4-bolt, and are completely incompatible with your 5-bolt Ultegra cranks. You could replace the entire chainset (aka crankset), but a modern Sora chainset will be incompatible with your bottom bracket (your Ultegra chainset uses a separate BB; the Sora and other higher-end Shimano chainsets today integrate the spindle into the left crankarm), so that would need to be replaced too. You might be better off looking for NOS Ultegra rings.
- Sora-grade chains are lower quality (less precise spacing between rivets), which will wear out the cassette and chainrings more quickly.
- The Sora cassette will work.

Comment: Correct chainrings are still made by Shimano and 3rd parties.

Comment: What awful bike do you think he rides where a groupset change is uneconomical? A good frame that fits well is worth more than a new bike that's cheaper than a groupset. Are you American?

Comment: Derailleurs at least are quite cheap, and do wear out over time even if they don't eat something and fail dramatically or get knocked and bent

Comment: I got new Ultegra ringchains (120 usd), and I would go for an ultegra chain with a Sora or 105 cassette for training. Maybe I can get a new ultegra cassette in the future for racing.

Comment: @ilciavo An Ultegra cassette isn't going to make you any faster.

Comment: @AndrewHenle It may do on the basis it will shift better and be marginally lighter. If marginal gains work for Team Sky...

Comment: @JoeK Team Sky rides what they get ***paid*** to ride.  All in the hopes of getting someone to pay more for something like an Ultegra cassette because it's got a different color finish and it's all of 1 gram lighter because the lock ring is aluminum instead of steel.

Comment: Stop being a troll. The 9sp ultegra has a steel lockring so it must be the more useful attributes making it better!